# Material Design 3 with Angular

Tags: angular, material-design

I am new to material design and I am researching whether I can use Material Design 3 with Angular version 17.

I have followed the steps mentioned in [Material Design 3](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/docs/quick-start.md) and successfully installed but I have no idea on how to use its components. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..!!

Comment: check this https://material.angular.io/

Comment: @KostasNitaf - as of version 17.0.1, `@angular/material` is still based on on Material 2, not 3. The question asks about Material 3. There are [mentions](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22738) that M3 should arrive with either upcoming minor, or next major version though, with some commits already pushed to experimental branch (i.e. [here](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/28148)).

Comment: Τhank you @TotallyNewb! It had not come to my attention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Material 3 support for Angular has been [released in v17.2](https://blog.angular.io/material-3-experimental-support-in-angular-17-2-8e681dde650e).

You can now use design tokens, customization becomes scary easy !

```
<mat-checkbox class="scary-setting">Delete my account</mat-checkbox>

.scary-setting {
  // No need to target any internal checkbox selectors! 
  - mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-state-layer-color: red;
  - mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-icon-color: red;
}
```